# Linq Distinct() or GroupBy() method is not working in below scenario

Tags: c#, linq

In below code I have multiple instance of the dictionary bundled into a list. Now I want to select only distinct values from the list. To do this I tried using **distinct and group by** but that never helped me. Can any one please help me in selecting only distinct using linq?

```
 IList<Dictionary<string, string>> lst = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> d1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            Dictionary<string, string> d3 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            d.Add("12345", "xyz");
            d1.Add("12345", "xyz");
            d3.Add("123456", "xyz-abc");
            lst.Add(d);
            lst.Add(d1);
            lst.Add(d3);
            var result = lst.Distinct(); //test => test.Values.ToString().Trim()); //.Select(grp => grp.First());
```

Comment: Distinct values meaning distinct dictionaries (that's what you are currently trying to do)? Or values across all the dictionaries (which would make more sense probably)?

Comment: You need to add a class implents `IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer`

Comment: It works as it should. All your three items within your list of dictionaries are unique.

Comment: Instances are different but values are same and I want to pick distinct the values that are same

Comment: You get three distinct dictionaries. Try `d["12345"] = "abc";` and you'll see that `d1["12345"]` is still `"xyz"`. If you want to say that you want to treat two (or more) dictionary as "the same" if they contain KeyValuePairs with "the same" keys and values, then you need to implement that logic in an `IEqualityComparer` and use it in this overload of [Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb338049.aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like get the distict values over all dictionaries then you need to compare the acctual elements in each dictionary to select all elements you could use SelectMany like this:

Key/Value pairs:

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(x=>x).Distinct();
```

Values:

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(x=>x.Values).Distinct();
```

Keys:

```
var result = lst.SelectMany(x=>x.Keys).Distinct();
```

Comment: This is going to compare the key value pairs rather than the values, is this what you mean?

Comment: Added examples for the different types of objects in the dictionaries

Comment: the retuen type is list of key value pair. where as I expected that to be List of Dictionary

Comment: Should this result.Cast<Dictionary<string, string>>().ToList(); work?

Comment: Do you want it to be a dictionary of the unique key/value pairs?

Then you could convert the list of value pairs to a dictionary using the ToDictionary method:

lst.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);

Comment: But the method from your last comment could throw if we have `KeyValuePair`s from different dictionaries that have the same key but different values to that key. Those would be distinct as pairs, but could not be put into a shared dictionary with the `.ToDictionary` extension method.

Comment: Jeppe, true good point. Sanju here is an example which group all the values for each unique key, then you will get a dictonary with the unique key and a corresponding list of the values for each key.

var result = lst.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().GroupBy(x => x.Key).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(v => v.Value).ToList());

Comment: @Mattis I need in the result in   IList<Dictionary<string, string>> result. Can let me know how to do this and contain only unique dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the values from the list first, then apply `Distinct()`:

```
var values = lst.SelectMany(dict => dict); // or lst.SelectMany(dict => dict.Values), I don't know what kind of values you mean
var distinctValues = values.Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` does not override the `Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()` methods. For that reason you get reference-equality semantics when you use `.Distinct()` (or `GroupBy` etc.).

`d` and `d1` refer two different instances (two different objects). These two dictionaries happen to have the same keys with the same corresponding values, but that does not make them the same instance. Therefore, `d != d1` (as references).

You might want to do instead:

```
var result = lst.Distinct(new YourDictEqualsComparer());
```

where `YourDictEqualsComparer` is the following class:

```
// naive string-string dictionary equality comparer
class YourDictEqualsComparer : EqualityComparer<Dictionary<string, string>>
{
  public override bool Equals(Dictionary<string, string> x, Dictionary<string, string> y)
  {
    if (x == null || y == null)
      return Default.Equals(x, y);

    if (!x.Comparer.Equals(y.Comparer))
      return false;

    var setOfPairs = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(x);
    return setOfPairs.SetEquals(y);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode(Dictionary<string, string> obj)
  {
    if (obj == null)
      return 0;

    int seed = obj.Comparer.GetHashCode();
    return obj.Aggregate(seed, (hash, pair) => hash ^ pair.GetHashCode());
  }
}
```